# how to convert svm score to probability and tune.svm function paratmeters

Tags: regression, machine-learning, svm

I am using following link as reference : https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/...

Although I’ve a few queries :

1. Is there a formula that will calculate predict function’s output on svm model on radial and polynomial kernels (the way we use in logistic regression Y = B0 + B1X 1+B2X 2+e and then put in logit func.)

2.I am using tune.svm function and summary of model gives me best performance value; but this value changes with the same cost and gamma every time I run the the code……… How is this value of best performance is calculated

3.Why tune.svm does give stable cost and gamma values? I am setting cost= seq(from=1,to=100,by=5) and gamma=(from=0.0005,to=0.05,by=0.005)…… Is there any other way to get the stable value

4.Lastly with reference to the link of analytic vidhya in the beginning, I use isoreg technique, but with this output of fits.isoreg gives only 13 unique levels out of 772 observation. This give me error when i use cut function in R for binning the probability values. (Error in cut.default(temp9$prob1, breaks = quantile(temp9$prob1, probs = seq(0, : 'breaks' are not unique )Can you please give help me out